# Bitbucket pipeline author

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I'm quite new to Bitbucket Pipelines. I currently defined three steps; 1 for testing, 1 for building and 1 manual trigger for deploying.

Is there any possible way to get the user which triggered the manual build (via environment variables for example).

Answer (score 1):

In the question title you speak of the author. This would be easy – simply ask Git, for instance using `git log -n 1 --format=format:'%an'`.

On the other hand, it is not possible to get the user who manually triggered a build, for instance using the “Rerun” button.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly how I check for the author right now. But that is not 100% of the times the real author (in our case). We will stick with this approach for now.

The strange thing is bitbucket has the information internally (because they show a picture of the author whenever a build is triggered manually).